# Sending SMS through PC using java via android mobile

Tags: java, android, sms

I would like to connect my mobile phone in USB debugging mode and then send sms through some java code, so that the text is actually send through my cellphone using my provider sms plan. I am without any idea. I googled but could not get anything useful. Any idea, approach or link to some tutorial would be very helpful.

Comment: Keep in mind that this most likely violates the terms of your plan.

Comment: I dont understand how? The provider would obviously charge me for sms.

Comment: Not obvious. And even if you pay *per SMS*, most terms I have come across forbid the use of your terminal as a connection or service proxying device unless specifically stated.

Comment: Such use are forbidden if I go for telemarketing. This is a personal application to test one of my development.

Comment: @NavedAlam have u done this and if yes how? can u please send me solution at info.shahid@yahoo.com

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor I end up using test plan of [Telerivet](https://telerivet.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest [SMS lib](http://smslib.org/)  for sending SMSs via your cell phone using Java code.
But if you are open to other ideas, I'd suggest to use a public webservice that sends in your place your SMSs, you can use for example [nexmo](https://www.nexmo.com/), they have very good api and charges very cheap SMS. You have an initial credit for starting.